# How do I make my image appear in relation to the size of a user's screen?

Tags: css, background-position

I have an image of that has a height of 480px.  On my Macbook it looks OK but when I go to my 30 inch monitor obviously there is a huge space in the bottom.

What can I do to make sure that the 480px will always be in relation so the size of the user's screen?

I did some searches and it seems that using background-image: cover or background position I can do some stuff but highly likely it's not what I am looking for.  What can I do tackle this issue?

Comment: Tried `background-size : 0 100%;`?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to place the image in a container that can scale with the page.

Height is a hard attribute to scale, but you can achieve it as long as all of the parent elements have a specified height as well.
You can use CSS code such as

```
height:40%;
```

to scale elements.

Scale the page's height here to see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/L7uWd/

Answer (score 0):

Try with the width in percentage to set the image size as per the browser width. It's always preferable to set the width in percentage(instead of pixel) while re-sizing the element based on window re-sizing.

Set the `image height to some percentage instead of pixel`, that will automatically handle with the size of the screen.